# Node.js socket.io with websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm begginer in Node.js or websocket. I have problem:

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            "use strict";
            var gniazdo = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
            gniazdo.onopen = function(){ 
                 console.log('Połączono');
            };
            gniazdo.onmessage = function(m){ 
                console.log(m.data); 
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Node.js code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

I have error in console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Help plz :)

Comment: Socket.io first tests the connection with long-polling and upgrades to websockets if they are supported. You need to use the socket.io client library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your client is using WebSockets, but Socket.IO has its own protocol (that *may* be transported over WebSockets, but it can also be transported over other protocols). Change your client to use Socket.IO's own client:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>

<script>

    'use strict';

    var gniazdo = io('ws://localhost:3000');

    gniazdo.on('connect', function () {

        console.log('Połączono');

        gniazdo.on('message', function (m) {
            console.log(m.data);
        });

    });

</script>
```